Route docker network traffic through cisco VPN connection on host
I have a bridge docker network and want the containers to be able to access devices on my company LAN through the CiscoAnyConnect VPN. (i.e. I want to route traffic from docker0 to cscotun0
However, I can't get it to work.
This is my bridge network:
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "5ec3c7c84c649c1126370d95cfaf7528e54c57a46e6070de02c14f55d7b5a218",
        "Created": "2024-04-03T09:25:23.699641867+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]

I have ip forwaring turned on:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
I can ping the outside world:
root@36610d5128e6:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=6.50 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=10.7 ms

But not a server on my VPN:
root@36610d5128e6:/# ping 192.168.119.179
PING 192.168.119.179 (192.168.119.179) 56(84) bytes of data.

Route:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.30.214.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
10.30.214.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
10.30.214.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wlp4s0
10.101.7.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
100.79.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 cscotun0
100.79.119.2    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cscotun0
100.79.119.3    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cscotun0
100.80.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 cscotun0
155.190.67.21   10.30.214.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br-2b540c1d9d5b
172.16.46.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.119.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
192.168.124.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
192.168.192.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
192.168.219.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 cscotun0
208.67.220.220  10.30.214.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp4s0
208.67.222.222  10.30.214.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlp4s0

I tried this:
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o cscotun0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i cscotun0 -o docker0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o cscotun0 -j ACCEPT

But that does not help. I'm new to iptables so I might be missing something, like conflicting config. What is the relevant command to display output for this?
Any hints on this approach?

See the post
Docker containers not accessible while connected on VPN :

I have faced this problem and tried all possible solutions available
in Internet, but nothing worked. It looks like Cisco Anyconnect vpn
takes an exclusive control over the routing of the system and any
changes made are not showing any effect.
The following worked for me. Instead of Cisco Anyconnect, use
OpenConnect VPN. Both uses same protocol. To download:
sudo apt install openconnect network-manager-openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome

Reboot your PC and then go to VPN Settings -> Multi-protocol VPN
client (open connect) and provide the settings as per your
organisation requirement.

